# Using LiE interpreter in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, interpreter, sage

Firstly, my background in programming is quite basic Python so Sage and everything that comes with it is very new to me, so apologies if I mix up terminology etc.

I am currently using an online version of LiE to assist me in performing some algebra based computations, but as the computations are getting quite complex I am hoping to move from pen and paper to sage math to perform these calculations for me.

I installed Sage and when I open SageMath notebook I am taken to Jupyter (which I guess is an IDE).

My issue is when I use Jupyter and try to run something like "lie.diagram('A2') I am presented with a bunch of errors which I do not understand.

I then tried a different interpreter, namely GAP, and this works fine e.g. if I input "gap(34).Factors()" then Jupyter will output "[2, 17]".

I checked the path "/opt/sagemath-9.2/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/" and both "gap.py" and "lie.py" are there, so I am unsure why gap works and lie does not.

Lastly, if I use the sage cell server and input "lie.diagram('A2')" then it does output the required diagram, so my guess is there is some behind the scenes issue between LiE and Jupyter specifically.

Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations on installing Sage. Knowing the operating system and how Sage was installed would help give a tailored answer. Jupyter provides the notebook interface and is unrelated to the problem: the error will be identical in the Sage REPL which you can run by opening a terminal and running `/opt/sagemath-9.2/sage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SageMath, GAP is a standard package, while
LiE is an optional package. This means when you
install Sage, you get GAP but you don't get LiE
unless you specifically ask for it.

On SageCell and CoCalc, the Sage installation
is very complete, with many optional packages
installed, so calling LiE works there.

The files in `.../sage/interfaces/` implement
the interfaces between Sage and other software,
and they are present whether or not the other
software is installed.

In your case, the interface to LiE exists,
but LiE is not installed, so when you run
a command such as `lie.diagram('A2'),`Sage
tries to talk to LiE using its LiE interface,
but does not find LiE and reports an error
which in my case looks like:

```
EOF ... Traceback (most recent call last)
...
EOF: End Of File (EOF). Empty string style platform.
...

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError ... Traceback (most recent call last)
...
RuntimeError: unable to start LiE: End Of File (EOF). Empty string style platform.
...

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError ... Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: unable to start LiE: End Of File (EOF). Empty string style platform.
...
```

To install LiE, if you built Sage from source,
open a terminal and run these command:

```
cd /opt/sagemath-9.2
make -s V=0 configure
./configure --enable-lie -q
make -s V=0
```

Next time you start Sage, you can use LiE:

```
sage: lie.diagram('A2')

O---O
1   2
A2
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes that is the exact error message I have! I believe I have used a binary install. I attempted to input the commands anyway but I got the message "make is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Would it be best for me to uninstall and attempt to reinstall Sage from source?

Comment: For `make` to work, you need to install some prerequisites (using e.g. `sudo apt install ...` on Debian or Ubuntu). You can also try `cd /opt/sagemath-9.2; ./sage -i lie`. If that also does not work, consider building from source. You could even build the latest development version, currently SageMath 9.4.beta5, in that case. Follow the instructions in the readme at https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/README.md or in the installation guide at https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/source.html

Comment: If you are on Windows, open the underlying Cygwin and install prerequisites there before you can run `make`.

Comment: I will try to build from source and see if the above answer works then. Unfortunately I am not so clued up on using command line etc so I really am pressing buttons and hoping for the best here!

Comment: After an afternoon of not being able to install it from source I have decided to just use CoCalc, I would not have realised that CoCalc had lie installed automatically so thank you for that. I have accepted your original answer as it was very helpful nonetheless. Thanks!